# how to upload excel file in mysql databse and check the file validation

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I need to upload a file in excel or csv format in mysql database,and code should also check for validation that each column should get appropriate value,
**for eg : name column should only get character input or no column should be empty.**
Here's a code which working for csv format,now please help me with excel file upload.
index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload your Files</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    body{
       background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/13/1356818.jpg);
    }
    p{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .hint
    {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    footer
    {
        text-align: center;
        width:100%;
        height:80px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CSV To MySql</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">How It Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
 </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class=" col-md-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="called.php" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>File Upload</p>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="hint">Only CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</div>

</form>
<footer>&copy;Parvez Alam</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**My php file
called.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{

    $host='localhost';
    $db_user= 'root';
    $db_password= '';
    $db= 'product_record';
    $conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");

        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

            $sql = "INSERT into prod_list_1(name,category,brand,price) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';

    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>
```

Comment: well for a start excel != csv

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use PDO or MySQLi.. `mysql` extension is depreciated.

I have had a similar issue before, though I needed to make sure that the values are not duplicated, and if there is a duplicate then a page should show me a notification.

The method I am using is different. I have a simple form to upload a csv file, a page to analyze the uploaded file, and once I am ok with the analysis, the file is uploaded to the database.

**File 1: csv_upload.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="csv_upload" name="csv_upload" action="csv_analysis.php" method="POST">
        <table border="0" width="40%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th height="30">Select csv File</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="50"><input name="file" type="file" /><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

**File 2: csv_analysis.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();

//DB Connection:
require "dbcon.php";

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

//Process the CSV file
$findings = '
    <form method="post" action="csv_upload_action.php">
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">No</th>
        <th width="19%">att0</th>
        <th width="19%">att1</th>
        <th width="19%">att2</th>
        <th width="19%">att3</th>
        <th width="19%">att4</th>
  </tr>';

$handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ","); //Remove if CSV file does not have column headings
$i = 1;
$insert_record          = 0;
$update_record          = 0;
$file_duplicate_count   = 0;
$file_duplicate         = array();

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {


        $att0   = $data[0];
        $att1   = $data[1];
        $att2   = $data[2];
        $att3   = $data[3];
        $att4   = $data[4];






    //Check if row is in database already : Notification shown but record overwritten in DB

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT *
                        FROM    table_name
                        WHERE   att0 =  '$att0'
                        AND     att1 = '$att1'
                        ");
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count > 0){
            $findings = $findings . '
        <tr class="'.$class.'">
            <td>'.$i.'</td>
            <td><font color="#FF6600"><b>DB Duplicate<b></font></td>'.
            '<td>'.$att0.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$att1.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$att2.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$att3.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$att4.'</td>'.
            '</tr>';

    //Update Statement:
    $_SESSION['insert'] .= "UPDATE table_name 
                                SET 
                                att2    = '$att2',
                                att3    = '$att3',
                                att4    = '$att4'
                                WHERE   att0 =  '$att0'
                                AND     att1 = '$att1'
                                ;";


    $update_record ++;

    }
    //Check if the record is a part of the file (File Duplicates):

    elseif(array_search($att0.strtotime($att1), $file_duplicate) != false)
    {

        $findings = $findings . '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$i.'</td>
        <td><font color="#FF6666"><b>File Duplicate<b></font></td>'.
        '<td>'.$att0.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att1.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att2.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att3.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att4.'</td>'.

    '</tr>';

    $file_duplicate_count ++;
    }

    //Row is unique
    else{
        //Add INSERT statement to INSERT queue
        $_SESSION['insert'] .= "INSERT INTO table_name
                                 (
                                    att0,
                                    att1,
                                    att2,
                                    att3,
                                    att4
                                    )

                                VALUES (
                                    '$att0',
                                    '$att1',
                                    '$att2',
                                    '$att3',
                                    '$att4',

                                );";
        $insert_record ++;

        //Add row for row to findings table and mark unique
        $findings = $findings . '
<tr class="'.$class.'">
        <td>'.$i.'</td>
        <td><font color="#3333CC"><b>OK</b></td>'.
        '<td>'.$att0.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att1.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att2.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att3.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$att4.'</td>'.'</tr>';

  }

$i++;

    //using the array (to be used as a unique identifier for file duplicates):
    $file_duplicate[]   = $att0.strtotime($att1);
    }

    $findings = $findings . '  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="13">
    <br>
        <center>
        Please note that entries that are highlighted with <b>"DB Duplicate"</b> will be updated in the schedule. This action can not be undone.
        </center>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Proceed" /></form><br><form action="upload_action.php"><input type="submit" value="Cancel" /></form>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

';
    $_SESSION['update_record']      =   $update_record;
    $_SESSION['insert_record']      =   $insert_record;
    $_SESSION['duplicated_records'] =   $file_duplicate_count;

    echo $findings;

}
else{
    header("Location:csv_upload.php");
}

?>
```

**File 3: csv_upload_action.php **

```
    <?php
session_start();

//DB Connection:
require "dbcon.php";



    $update_record          =   $_SESSION['update_record'];
    $insert_record          =   $_SESSION['insert_record'];
    $file_duplicate_count   =   $_SESSION['duplicated_records'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['insert'])){

        header("Location:csv_upload.php");
    }
$queries = explode(';', $_SESSION['insert']);

foreach($queries as $query){
    if($query != ""){
        $stmt   =   $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
}

echo "<center><br><br>CSV File uploaded<br>";

if($insert_record != 0){
    echo $insert_record." records added to the database.<br>";
}


if($update_record != 0){
    echo $update_record." records were modified.<br>";
}

if($file_duplicate_count != 0){
    echo $file_duplicate_count." records were duplicated in the uploaded file, they were not written to the database.<br>";
}

unset($_SESSION['insert']);
?>
```

Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.